# Get more than 100 most trending tweets using Twitter4j

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

Hello There I need to get more than 100 Most Trending Tweets from Twitter using twitter4j API!
I have been trying as of my following code

---

```
     private static void getMostTrendingTweets(){
        try{
            // The factory instance is re-useable and thread safe.
            Twitter twitter = TwitterFactory.getSingleton();
            Query query = new Query("#google");
            query.setCount(500);
            QueryResult result = twitter.search(query);
            int c=0;
            for (Status status : result.getTweets()) {
                System.out.println("Status@\t" + status.getUser().getScreenName() + "\t:\t" + status.getText());
                c+=1;
            }
            System.out.println("SIZE=== "+c);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
```

---

But the problem is that it always give 100 tweets maximum!

Is it me doing something wrong or is it not possible to get more than 100 tweets. What am I doing wrong?

Also can somebody give me any idea about any other Java Library to get tweets from Twitter using Java!

Thanks in advance

Comment: I suspect this is a twitter api block

Comment: yes its an example from the office twitter4j website! I just posted here just for an example

Answer (score 0):

The *search/tweets* endpoint is constrained to a maximum of 100 tweets, so even though you can set the parameter to 500 in Twitter4j, the Twitter API won't give you more than 100:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/search/tweets

You should use the *trends/place* endpoint to get the list of trending topics. Here again, the number of trends returned is constrained to 50:

https://dev.twitter.com/rest/reference/get/trends/place

Here's the Twitter4j docs on that endpoint:

http://twitter4j.org/javadoc/twitter4j/api/TrendsResources.html#getPlaceTrends(int)

So, your query might look like:

```
    int world = 1;
    Trends topTrends = getPlaceTrends(world);
```

Looking at Twitter Libraries, I only see Twitter4j. However, you could search GitHub or other source code repositories to see if there are others, which there usually are. When making your decision about library, keep in mind that they are only able to perform the tasks allowed with the specified parameter constraints that the Twitter API allows.

Twitter4j has API docs, but the Twitter API documentation is the ultimate resource for cross-checking parameters, return values, and endpoint behavior:

https://dev.twitter.com/overview/documentation

Comment: can you give an example for it?